# Is $\arctan(y/x) > xy/(x^{2}+y^{2})$ true for positive $x,y$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

I am trying to prove the following:
$$\arctan\frac{y}{x}>\frac{xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}},\quad\forall x,y>0$$
Is the statement true, and if so how do you prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First substitute $t=y/x$, and establish

$$\arctan(t)>\frac t{1+t^2}.$$

We have

$$\arctan(0)=\frac 0{1+0^2},$$ and by differentiation,

$$\frac1{1+t^2}>\frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}=\frac1{1+t^2}\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}.$$

The last fraction is obviously bounded by $1$, so that the property holds for all $t>0$.

Comment: You cannot differentiate the both side of an inequality. It is a wrong mathematical statement because the "order $\le$ or $\ge$" is not valid in case of differentiation. e.g., it is well known that $\tan x <x$ for all $x$. Differentiating both sides we get $\sec^2 x <1$ i.e., $\cos^2 x >1$ which is not true.

Comment: @mwomath: for a continuously differentiable function (which is the case here) and ensuring that the property holds for at least one point (which I showed), the property holds. (As you said, $\tan(x)<x$ is true for all $x\in(0,\pi/2)$ for the same reason.) Thank you to undo the downvote.

Comment: @mwomath, you might be thinking of the inequality $\sin x\lt x$.  The inequality you cited actually goes the other way:  $\tan x\gt x$ (but only for $0\lt x\lt\pi/2$).

Comment: @BarryCipra: thanks for the correction. Obviously !

Comment: I am not discussing the validity of the inequality. I aloof about the proof.

Comment: Another example: $\ln x < x-1$ for all $x>0$. differentiate both sides $\frac{1}{x}<1$ which is not true at least for $0<x<1$. Another one: $\exp(-x) \ge 1-x$ for all $x\ge0$ but $ \exp(-x) \le 1$ for all $x>0$

Comment: @mwomath: you are still missing the point. As $\ln(1)=1-1$, for all $x>1$, $1/x<1$, then $\ln(x)<x-1$. Your second example is the first with $x\leftrightarrow e^{-x}$.

Comment: Also, $\tan x < x$ for every $x \in Dom(\tan)$

Comment: @mwomath Hem, what about $\tan(\pi/4)$ vs. $\pi/4$ ?

Comment: it is ok $\tan x < k x$ for a suitable $k$ (i am sure about that).  Forget this and look to the examples above

Comment: $\ln x < x-1$ for all **$x>0$** the inequality after differentiation broken in case $0<x<1$

Comment: @mwomath: "I am sure about that". Of course not, $\tan(x)$ is unbounded.

Comment: @mwomath: stop being blind. The inequality doesn't hold for $x<1$ because $\ln(1)=1-1$. It does hold for $x>1$ for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Consider the function $h:y\mapsto \arctan\tfrac yx-\tfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$. What is $h'(y)$? Is it strictly positive? What can you conclude then?

Comment: Indeed, $h'(y)$ is strictly positive which proves that $h(y) > 0$ for all $y$. But does this prove it for all $x$ as well? If I take the derivative w.r.t. to $x$ I end up with a strictly negative expression. Don't I have to prove it along both axes?

Comment: @Michael To prove that $h'(y)\gt0$ you already assume that $x\gt0$. If you want to take the derivative with respect to $x$, then how are you going to proceed to prove that $h(x)\gt0$ or $h(x)\lt0$ when the function wouldn't even be defined for $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $y/x=u\gt0$, the inequality to prove becomes

$$\arctan u\gt{u\over1+u^2}$$

For $u\gt0$, we have

$$\arctan u=\int_0^u{dt\over 1+t^2}\gt\int_0^u{dt\over1+u^2}={u\over 1+u^2}$$

since $1+t^2\lt1+u^2$ for $0\lt t\lt u$.

Alternatively, rewrite the inequality as

$${1\over2}(x^2+y^2)\arctan(y/x)\gt{1\over2}xy$$

and reinterpret the left hand side as ${1\over2}r^2\theta$ where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\tan\theta=y/x$.  The left hand side is thus the area of a circular wedge that *contains* a right triangle of height $y$ and base $x$ (with hypotenuse $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$), whose area is expressed by the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Write $y=\sin \theta$, $x=\cos \theta$, then we need to prove: $\theta > \sin \theta \cos \theta$ in $(0,\pi/2)$, multiplying by 2, $x> \sin x$ for $x \in (0, \pi)$ which is true.